# What is the best way to convert array of interface into array of map in golang?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

I've created a web server and this server is able to get POST request. However, when I send array of map[string]string in POST data, server receives it as array of interface{}. How can I convert it back to array of map[string]string?

Example : Like when I send following example in POST request,

```
params : [{"name" : "shail", "age" : 24}]
```

I'm sending params as

```
[](map[string]string)
```

but when server receives this data, it treats params as

```
[]interface{}
```

.How do I assign params in a variable defined by

```
[](map[string]interface{})
```

?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I send?" Do you Marshall this into JSON and then Unmarshall it? How are you Unmarshalling it? Are you sending GOB instead of JSON? What code you "receives it as array of interface{}?" There is no standard web protocol that sends "interface{}". Have you looked at the examples in `encoding/json`?

Comment: Agreed. I provided an admittedly dumb answer below - you can Unmarshal the JSON payload on a struct and get type safety and more code clarity.....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is a type assertion on the values:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var source []interface{}
    var test = make(map[string]string, 0)
    test["hello"] = "World"
    source = append(source, test)
    var dest = source[0].(map[string]string)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(dest).Kind())
    fmt.Println(dest["hello"])
}
```